# Unwanted double quote in first line of file being written out

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a to a txt file and the first character in the first line, when I view the file in notepad is a double quote.  If I examine the variables that get written out when the code is running, the double quote is not there.  Any ideas what might be wrong?  Here is my code snippet:

```
mydata1 = "!TRNS" & vbTab & vbTab & "TRNSID" & vbTab & "TRNSTYPE" & vbTab & 
"DATE" & vbTab & "ACCNT" & vbTab & "CLASS" & vbTab & "AMOUNT" & vbTab & 
"DOCNUM" & vbTab & "MEMO" & vbCrLf
mydata1 = mydata1 & "!SPL" & vbTab & "SPLID" & vbTab & "TRNSTYPE" & vbTab & 
"DATE" & vbTab & "ACCNT" & vbTab & "CLASS" & vbTab & "AMOUNT" & vbTab & 
"DOCNUM" & vbTab & "MEMO" & vbCrLf
mydata1 = mydata1 & "!ENDTRNS" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & 
vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbCrLf
mydata1 = mydata1 & "TRNS" & vbTab & "GENERAL JOURNAL" & vbTab & myDate & 
vbTab & "ACCOUNTS REC-CORP OFFICE" & vbTab & "CORPORATE OFFICE" & vbTab & 
mytot & vbTab & myDate & vbTab & vbCrLf
mydata1 = mydata1 & mydata2
file = "d:\junk\todd\tester.txt"
Open myfile For Output As #1
Write #1, mydata1
Close #1
```

Comment: `mydata1 = Chr(34) & "!TRNS" …` If you want a `"` in the beginning. • Alternatively use a doubled `"` within your string `mydata1 = """!TRNS" …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below syntax and see if it works for you:

`Print #1, mydata1`

BTW, the variable myfile and file do not match in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, the Print worked like a charm.  Thanks for the warning on the file variable!